# Trying retrofit in flutter and getting errors when making restclient

Tags: flutter, retrofit

I'm following [this](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) and getting errors "The name _RestClient isn't a type and can't be used in a redirected constructor.)

How do i solve it?

```
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:utstyrapp/models/Item.dart';


@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://localhost:8080/")
abstract class RestClient {
  factory RestClient(Dio dio) = _RestClient;

  @GET("/items")
  Future<List<Item>> getItems();
}
```

Comment: I have same issue. Did You solve the problem?

Comment: `Item` should be in the same file as `RestClient `

Comment: @brosuf you should install `retrofit_generator` package

Answer (score 10):

if any help still needed, i solve so:

**install all deps ->**

```
dependencies:
  retrofit: any    

dev_dependencies:
  retrofit_generator: any
  build_runner: any
```

**clean all ->**

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter packages upgrade
```

**add this to your service ->**

```
part 'your_rest_client_filename.g.dart';
```

**generate it all again ->**

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```