# The name _ApiClient isn't a type and can't be used in a redirected constructor

Tags: flutter, retrofit, dio

I am using retrofit in the flutter, this code was worked fine until I upgrade the retrofit version.
I am a newbie in a flutter. Please help me to resolve this error.
Here is my code snippet.

```
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:abc/views/home/models/categorymodel.dart';
part 'api_client.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000")
abstract class ApiClient {
  factory ApiClient(Dio dio) = _ApiClient;

  @GET("/categories")
  Future<CategoryModel> getCategories(@Queries() Map<String, dynamic> queries);
}
```

Comment: `CategoryModel` should be in the same file as `ApiClient `

Answer (score 1):

this is answered in this question here [Trying retrofit in flutter and getting errors when making restclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572622/trying-retrofit-in-flutter-and-getting-errors-when-making-restclient)

the actual reason behind could be missing the `retrofit_generator` in the dev_dependencies inside `pubspec.yaml` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `retrofit_generator` was missing in my pubspec.yaml file.